# Javascript split with multiple characters returning empty element

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
const str = "income[1].selected"
```

I would like to get a 3 separate elements by splitting this string by `[`, `]`, and `.` characters.
I have tried to do it by:

```
field.split(/[[\].]/)
```

But, that gives me 4 elements:

```
(4) ['income', '1', '', 'selected']
```

What kind of regex do I need to avoid empty string element?

Comment: You can repeat the character class `[[\].]+`

Comment: I would recommend against a regex in this case, you are parsing, not card punching here.

Comment: How would you parse it to get what I need? @Kris

Comment: I would find or create a (typescript) PropertyPath library (like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173978/javascript-of-property-path-in-object)